# Ajax sequential result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a bit of code to divide a string of words in parts and do a request (foreach part) to php to get results and place them in element. All works fine when I use async : false BUT I would like it to be be async : true. The problem I have with async : true is that the results are "random" because request doesn't goes sequential... I've read and searched how to solve this but couldn't find it...

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
$("#check").on( "click", function() {
    $("#results").empty();
    var text = $("#original").val();
    var totalWords = text.split(' ').length;
    var start = 0;
    var numberResults = 10;
    var divide = totalWords / numberResults;
    var numberOfTimes = Math.floor(divide) + 1;
    var test = 0;
    for(var index = 0; test < totalWords; index+=10){
        var part = text.split(/\s+/).slice((test),(test + 10)).join(" ");           
        $.ajax({
          url: "requests.php",
          async : true,
          cache: false,
          type: "POST",
          data: {words : part},           
          success: function(html){
            $("#results").append(html);
            $("#check").hide();         
          }
        });
        console.log(test);
        test = test + 10;   
        $(".progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", test);
        $(".progress-bar").css({"min-width" : test + "em"});
        $(".progress-bar").css({"width" : test + "%"});
        $(".progress-bar").text(test + "%");
        console.log(part);
    }   
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous Execution cannot guaranty order of execution. Hence the name. If you want synchronous as you mentioned use `async: false`.
[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Alternatively, use a solution to rearrange the data or use some additional parameter to position the data in your required order if you want to reap the advantages of async execution such as speed.

Example of one such implementation logic is:

```
$(function() {
    $("#check").on("click", function() {
        $("#results").empty();
        var text = $("#original").val();
        var totalWords = text.split(' ').length;
        var start = 0;
        var numberResults = 10;
        var divide = totalWords / numberResults;
        var numberOfTimes = Math.floor(divide) + 1;
        var test = 0;

        function action_task(index, data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "requests.php",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                success: function(html) {
                    //add data at reserved spot
                    $("#id_" + index).html(html);
                    $("#check").hide();
                }
            });
        }
        for (var index = 0; test < totalWords; index += 10) {
            var part = text.split(/\s+/).slice((test), (test + 10)).join(" ");
            //reserving a spot
            $("#results").append("<span id='id_" + index + "'></span>");
            action_task(index, {
                words: part
            });
            console.log(test);
            test = test + 10;
            $(".progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", test);
            $(".progress-bar").css({
                "min-width": test + "em"
            });
            $(".progress-bar").css({
                "width": test + "%"
            });
            $(".progress-bar").text(test + "%");
            console.log(part);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Iceman, I'm going for your alternative solution for the speed advantage...trying it only left me with one problem.... the new spans stays emtpy.... trying to figure it out why wright now....you can see result at [link](http://www.matox.nl/content)

Comment: Hi Iceman, I'm going for your alternative solution for the speed advantage...trying it only left me with one problem.... the new spans stays emtpy.... trying to figure it out why wright now....you can see result at [link](http://www.matox.nl/content) <br/><br/> Ok, as you can see in the console the elements are wrongely placed because wrong id-number....I had a problem with the index before, that's why you also have a 'test'-counter in it...

Comment: As you can see in the console the id which is used (for all) is 110. And the divs are till id 100. Could you please have another look at it @Iceman ? Can't find why myself...it seems ok....! :(

Comment: do a console.log on the html from the success callback

Comment: @KnapLelijk check if the right data is being received

Comment: You can already see in the console that the correct data is being returned but the counter is someway "lost" in the ajax-call and always uses 110.... Just for your info: I'm making this tool to replace words with synonyms.

Comment: As you can see the counter works when it's not used within the ajax-request (console.log(test);)

Comment: let me look thru again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116317/discussion-between-iceman-and-knaplelijk).

Comment: try to user forEach instead of for loop

Comment: @JackTurky working now. I passed control variable to another function.